# rspec before context without js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a feature test I have 2 feature macros: `sign_in` and `add_to_cart`. User logs in without JS, but for `add_to_cart` a JS macros is needed.

spec:

```
  describe 'User add product in cart' do
      before { sign_in(user) }

      scenario 'and view cart stuff' do

        add_to_cart(product, 2)
        visit cart_path

      end
  end
```

feature macros

```
module FeaturesMacros
  def sign_in(user)
    visit sign_in_path 
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
  end


  def add_to_cart(product, quantity)
    visit product_path(id: product.id)
    fill_in 'line_item_quantity', with: quantity
    click_button 'Add to Cart'
  end
end
```

When I run test without JS, error is

> ActionController::UnknownFormat: LineItemsController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

If I add JS `for scenario 'and view cart stuff', js: true do`, I have error in user login:

> Failure/Error: visit sign_in_path.

How to add JS in scenario, but remove it from `before` context? Maybe there are better methods?

Comment: What is the specific error you get? ("Failure/Error: visit sign_in_path.")

Comment: for login user must visit sign in page (/sign_in), but if JS enabled user cannot visit this page.